# Storing user data in database with out Escaping

Tags: php, mysql

Most of my questions are theoretical in nature since I think "Great minds discuss Ideas" and clerks discuss syntax.

Anyways.. so here is the situation

I have a system which take input from user.BUT none of that input is used in queries (at all). This input contain a lot of code snippets. Now in the past i escaped the input and then stored it in database. I do not use adding and stripping slashes functions of any sort rather use my own procedures which use preg_replace like following

```
$data = preg_replace("/\;/", "&#59;", $data);//
$data = preg_replace("/</", "&lt;",   $data);
$data = preg_replace("/>/", "&gt;",   $data);
$data = preg_replace("/\"/", "&quot;",$data);
$data = preg_replace("/\(/", "&#40;", $data);
```

However following problems occurred.

At times the software will escape the data wrongly (since my software is not bug free) and I will have no way of finding what the actual data was.
From time to time I update my escaping procedures and that means different inputs are escaped differently.

the user has an option to EDIT his post. thus it means that i have to present him the escaped data (or un escape the data) to prevent escaping a data twice......
SO finally i have come to the conclusion that I save un-escaped data from user directly into database. and escape it before Display (it has no other purpose.. no use in query etc). for any thing else i have the original data un changed.

My Questions::

Can un escaped user data in database still be  dangerous even when not used in queries or escaped before display???

Is Escaping with slashes equal / better /different than escaping by chaging characters eg < into <..

If the data is properly escaped ( i mean all special characters) can it still be used for XSS attack. SQL injection is out of question.

Answer (score 12):

**Never** encode data for display *until you are actually going to display it*. When storing, encode for storage, when transmitting, encode for transmission, etc. The proper encoding at the proper time will handle these issues for you.

Comment: So short yet such a great answer. +1

Comment: I would also add "never write your own escaping functions".

Comment: ohh... ya makes so much sense.. can you plz direct me to some place to read more about...What is encoding for display...what is encoding for storage....THANKS

Answer (score 0):

Yes it can be dangerous.  The user could easily inject code to run his own queries on your database (even if you don't intend to query this data).